# MySQL Sub Query difficulty

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a count of how many times a user has triggered the following query. And I've concluded that a Sub Query is required.
The below (admittedly indelicate) query works, as far as it goes, *without* the Sub Query. And the Sub Query works as a *standalone* query. But after three days of trying, I cannot get the two to work combined. I don't know if I have a glaring syntax error, or whether I'm getting it all wrong in principle. I need help!

```
SELECT id, status, FirstName, LastName, Track, KeyChange, Version, 
DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(Created,'+00:00','+1:00'), '%l:%i %p') AS Created_formatted, 
TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, pinknoise.Created, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL '0' HOUR)),'%Hh %im') AS elapsed,
(SELECT `FirstName`, Count(*) AS 'CountRequests' FROM `pinknoise` GROUP by `FirstName`)
FROM pinknoise 
WHERE status = 'incoming' 
ORDER BY Created DESC
```

Comment: For starters, you need a comma after "AS elapsed."  Also, what do you mean by "I can't get it to work?"  Are there error messages?  Are the results not what you expect?

Comment: MySQL is usually *extremely* specific about where the mistake is. Pay careful attention to the exact wording of the error message.

Comment: Ah yes, a comma is needed after AS elapsed. Thanks. But that's not the only error, as previous attempts have contained the comma. As for it 'not working' - it returns a completely empty results set!

Comment: And that's a completely empty result set with no error message!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what your query should achieve, but well formatted it looks like:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    status, 
    FirstName, 
    LastName, 
    Track, 
    KeyChange, 
    Version, 
    DATE_FORMAT(
        CONVERT_TZ(
            Created,
            '+00:00',
            '+1:00'
        ), 
        '%l:%i %p'
    ) AS Created_formatted, 
    TIME_FORMAT(
        SEC_TO_TIME(
            TIMESTAMPDIFF(
                SECOND, 
                pinknoise.Created, 
                CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL '0' HOUR
            )
        ),
        '%Hh %im'
    ) AS elapsed
    (
        SELECT 
            `FirstName`, 
            Count(*) AS 'CountRequests' 
        FROM 
            `pinknoise` 
        GROUP by 
            `FirstName`
    )
FROM 
    pinknoise 
WHERE 
    status = 'incoming' 
ORDER BY 
    Created DESC
```

What I imagine: you want the number of total entries for this particular firstname in the same table. The dirty way would be:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    status, 
    FirstName, 
    LastName, 
    Track, 
    KeyChange, 
    Version, 
    DATE_FORMAT(
        CONVERT_TZ(
            Created,
            '+00:00',
            '+1:00'
        ), 
        '%l:%i %p'
    ) AS Created_formatted, 
    TIME_FORMAT(
        SEC_TO_TIME(
            TIMESTAMPDIFF(
                SECOND, 
                pinknoise.Created, 
                CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL '0' HOUR
            )
        ),
        '%Hh %im'
    ) AS elapsed,
    (
        SELECT 
            Count(*) 
        FROM 
            `pinknoise` AS tb
        WHERE
            tb.FirstName = pinknoise.FirstName
    ) AS CountRequests
FROM 
    pinknoise 
WHERE 
    status = 'incoming' 
ORDER BY 
    Created DESC
```

A much better performance would have a join:

```
SELECT 
    pinknoise.id, 
    pinknoise.status, 
    pinknoise.FirstName, 
    pinknoise.LastName, 
    pinknoise.Track, 
    pinknoise.KeyChange, 
    pinknoise.Version, 
    DATE_FORMAT(
        CONVERT_TZ(
            pinknoise.Created,
            '+00:00',
            '+1:00'
        ), 
        '%l:%i %p'
    ) AS Created_formatted, 
    TIME_FORMAT(
        SEC_TO_TIME(
            TIMESTAMPDIFF(
                SECOND, 
                pinknoise.Created, 
                CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL '0' HOUR
            )
        ),
        '%Hh %im'
    ) AS elapsed,
    tabA.CountRequests
FROM 
    pinknoise 
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            Count(*) AS 'CountRequests',
            FirstName
        FROM 
            `pinknoise`
        GROUP BY
            FirstName
    ) tabA
ON
    pinknoise.FirstName = tabA.FirstName
WHERE 
    status = 'incoming' 
ORDER BY 
    Created DESC
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I posted, but you were first.  Sorry about that.  If this is the correct answer, credit should go to you.

Comment: @ghenghy yes have seen your answer, too, after i finished my long post. but I think we thought the right way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your subselect is returning 2 values in the select portion where it only expects one value.  I'm guessing you are getting the FirstName with the intent of doing a join.  If so, then try this:

```
SELECT 
    p.id, 
    p.status, 
    p.FirstName, 
    p.LastName, 
    p.Track, 
    p.KeyChange, 
    p.Version, 
    DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(p.Created,'+00:00','+1:00'), '%l:%i %p') AS Created_formatted, 
    TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, p.Created, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL '0' HOUR)),'%Hh %im') AS elapsed,
    cnt.CountRequests
FROM 
    pinknoise p
    inner join (SELECT p.FirstName, Count(*) AS CountRequests FROM pinknoise p GROUP by p.FirstName) cnt on p.FirstName = cnt.FirstName
WHERE 
    p.status = 'incoming' 
ORDER BY 
    p.Created DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help so far - all of you. I'm stuck on a dodgy public connection at the moment and testing isn't easy. But you folk are amazing and I'm sure your brilliant 'tidy ups' will help me out. I'll be back crying on your shoulders tomorrow if not!

Comment: Hey chaps. I just got this to fly! Please advise as to who gets the credit? It was ghenghy's answer that flew, but I saw comments suggesting that Marcel posted first. Either way, massive thanks. Do let me know who is owed a green tick.

Comment: I think it's the same answer and Marcel got it first.  So I'd give it to him.